# Getting error with fs.rename with NODEjs

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, fs

I copied the source code from the tutorial for this page so I must have something wrong with my file path somewhere. Here is the error I am getting

Error->
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Amazo\AppData\Local\Temp\3OOis2VHktYYKr2gQCX97Y2X.jpg' -> 'c:\Users\Amazo\Nodejs\SocialMediaProject1\uploads\568ab3707d355a981c73d41dWed Jan 06 2016 08:26:35 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)207330aba4a36cea73e8ed6fda9cb012.jpg'

Here is my code:

```
var User = require('../datasets/users');
var fs = require('fs-extra');
var path = require('path');

module.exports.updatePhoto = function (req, res){
    var file = req.files.file;
    var userId = req.body.userId;

    console.log("User " + userId + " is submitting " , file);
    var uploadDate = new Date();


    var tempPath = file.path;
    var targetPath = path.join(__dirname, "../../uploads/" + userId + uploadDate + file.name);
    var savePath = "/uploads/" + userId + uploadDate + file.name;

    fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, function (err){
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            User.findById(userId, function(err, userData){
                var user = userData;
                user.image = savePath;
                user.save(function(err){
                    if (err){
                        console.log("failed save")
                        res.json({status: 500})
                    } else {
                        console.log("save successful");
                        res.json({status: 200})
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: And you checked the given path and filename, and the file does in fact exist, even if Node says it doesn't, and now you're wondering why Node doesn't find the file that is clearly there, just where it says it shouldn't be.

Comment: Yes when I go into C:\Users\Amazo\AppData\Local\Temp\3OOis2VHktYYKr2gQCX97Y2X.jpg ,It is 100% there. Something that fixed this for some reason was when I put .toISOString on the new Date() part. So where var uploadDate = new Date().toISOString and it works why is it I have to add that but he does not? To be honest I have no clue what that does.

Answer (score 1):

From much looking and research I have found that this error does not really tell you which path is actually wrong. So in this case I believe it to be the second path to be wrong as the first path is 100% true and exists.

What I did is in the:

```
 var uploadDate = new Date();
```

I added:

```
uploadDate = uploadDate.toString;
```

This made it work for me. Not to sure why to be a 100% honest , but it must have something to do with how the rename function works with the fs node module. Either way if anyone else has feedback let me know what you find.